# LinearLayout doesn't show when I put it into a ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

I have a LinearLayout with deferents views, and it displays normally when install it in my phone. But I want to put that LinearLayout into a ContraintLayout, however when I did it, nothing is display in my screen.

This code works well

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

    </data>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/short_cuts_bottom_menu_layout_height"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <!-- Views -->

        </LinearLayout>


</layout>
```

But this doesn't works

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/short_cuts_bottom_menu_layout_height"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <!-- Views -->

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

And I just put my LinearLayout into a ConstraintLayout

Someone knows why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `android:layout_width` attribute in `ConstraintLayout` should have the value `match_parent` because the `LinearLayout` inside it has the same

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Answer (score 1):

By assigning *wrap_content* to the width of your ConstraintLayout, you tell it to define its dimension based on the dimensions of its children. And by assigning *match_parent* to the width of your LinearLayout you tell it to define its dimension based on its parent. So they keep asking each other, nobody knows :)

You can simply assign *match_parent* to the width of your constraint layout